# How to type correctly fetch in React/Redux/TS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm writing an app with React, Redux and TS. Right now I stuck into problem with Promises and TS. Could you help me to type functions/Promises?

1. API call returns a list of posts id e.g. [1, 2, ..., 1000].
2. I need to render only 100 posts on a page.
3. To do that I created four functions:

- **checkResponse()** - checks if res.ok then return res.json() or
  throws an error.
- **fetchStoryIdList()** - makes API call for an array of all ids.
- **fetchStoryList()** - makes API call for every single id and returns
  and array of 100 posts.
- **fetchStories()** - dispatches to store array of posts.

At the moment TS shows an error in `fetchStories()` in this line `dispatch(fetchStorySuccessAction(storyList))` .

Error message

```
Argument of type '[unknown, ..., unknown]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IStory[]'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'IStory'.
```

IStory interface

```
export interface IStory {
  by: string;
  descendants: number;
  id: number;
  kids: number[];
  score: number;
  time: number;
  title: string;
  type: string;
  url: string;
}
```

IStoryState interface

```
export interface IStoryState {
  storyList: IStory[];
  storyError: null | string;
  isStoryLoading: boolean;
}
```

Action fetchStorySuccessAction

```
export const fetchStorySuccessAction = (storyList: IStory[]): IFetchStoryDataSuccessAction => {
  return {
    type: StoryActionTypes.FETCH_STORY_DATA_SUCCESS,
    payload: storyList,
  };
};
```

API functions

```
const checkResponse = (response: Response) => {
  return response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(`Ошибка с фронта`);
};

const fetchStoryIdList = async (): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/newstories.json`);
    const idJson: number[] = await checkResponse(response);
    return idJson;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};


const fetchStoryList = async () => {
  const idList = await fetchStoryIdList();
  const promises = idList.slice(0, 100).map(async (id: number) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/item/${id}.json`);
      const storyData: IStory = await checkResponse(response);
      return storyData;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
  const storyList = await Promise.all(promises);

  return storyList;
};


const fetchStories = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<StoryActions>) => {
    try {
      dispatch(fetchStoryAction());
      const storyList = await fetchStoryList();

    // TS error happens here
    // but I thinks all functions have to be typed somehow
      dispatch(fetchStorySuccessAction(storyList));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Add body of `fetchStorySuccessAction`

Comment: @MateuszPiguła added

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs because of the returned array response of `fetchStoryList()` is not the type of `IStory`. Therefor you have to explicitly cast the type of returned array `unknown[]` to `IStory[]` array.

In `fetchStories` function,

```
const fetchStories = () => {
  ...
    const storyList = (await fetchStoryList()).map(e => e as IStory);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` doesn't know its type. Try the solution below.

```
const promises: Promise<IStory | void>[] = idList.slice(0, 100).map(async (id: number) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/item/${id}.json`);
      const storyData: IStory = await checkResponse(response);
      return storyData;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```